# Как сделать затемнение по всей рамке?

Tags: html, css

подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы тень при наведении на div покрывала его полностью?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который сейчас:

```css
.ach_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  border:1.5px solid rgb(62, 66, 69);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
}

.desc_achievement {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: rgb(124, 125, 129);
  opacity: 0;
}

.ach_block:hover .desc_achievement {
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 1px;
}

.name_achievement {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(124, 125, 129);
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ach_block:hover .name_achievement {
 opacity: 0;
}

.ico_achievement {
 height: 50px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ach_block" onclick="get_unif(this);">
  <img class="ico_achievement" id="" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2014/1/633/w128h1281390857183sale128.png">
  <p class="name_achievement">text 1</p>
  <p class="desc_achievement">text2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: убрать абсолютное позиционирование у текста

Comment: @meine, можете дать пример? ну вот я убираю абсолютную позицию у текста, и он уплывает, да и тень вместе с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.ach_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
  border:1.5px solid rgb(62, 66, 69);
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
}
.desc_achievement {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: rgb(124, 125, 129);
  opacity: 0;

}
.ach_block:hover  {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: block

}
.name_achievement {
  position: absolute;
  color: rgb(124, 125, 129);
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.ico_achievement {
 height: 50px;
 float: right;
```

```html
<div class="ach_block" onclick="get_unif(this);">
  <img class="ico_achievement" id="" src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2014/1/633/w128h1281390857183sale128.png">
  <p class="name_achievement">text 1</p>
  <p class="desc_achievement">text2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за решение!

Comment: --- Пожалуйста)

Comment: @Coder Теперь репа позволит везде комментировать

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  width: max-content;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.block:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.block:hover .block__desc {
  display: block;
}

.block:hover .block__title {
  display: none;
}

.block::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.block__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.block__title {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.block__desc {
  display: none;
}

.block__image {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.block__image>img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block__wrapper">
      <div class="block__group">
        <div class="block__title">Lorem, ipsum.</div>

        <div class="block__desc">Lorem, ipsum.</div>
      </div>

      <div class="block__image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за пример